# R - In a for loop iterating through columns df[[i]] if a data frame, how do I print the name of column df[[i]] for each loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for-loop to iterate through the columns of a data frame, and for each loop print out the name of the column on each loop before the operation is performed (namely checking if there are missing values for that column).

I have tried all I can think of, but haven't had any luck so far.

This was my best guess, but it just returns NULL for the column name (I'm guessing because once I've extracted the data of the column it's already a nameless vector?).

```
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  # Print column name
  print(colnames(df[[i]]))
  # Print sum of missing values for each column
  print(sum(is.na(df[[i]])))
  # Print NA value rows
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
NULL
[1] 70
NULL
[1] 0
NULL
[1] 0
NULL
[1] 0
NULL
```

What can I do to print the column name for each pass?

Comment: Try: `colSums(is.na(df))`

Comment: If we have to use the forloop, change the first print to: `print(colnames(df)[ i ])` or `print(colnames(df[ i ]))`. By using double brackets you are losing the structure, names are dropped, hence getting NULL.

Comment: As hinted by @zx8754, you do know you don’t *have* to use a loop to do this, right?

Comment: Ohhhhh, thanks @zx8754 (and Limey). I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to look at the `names` of `df` and `print` the `i`th one.
Basically, move your square brackets out one brace and make them single:

```
df <- data.frame(pigs = c("straw","sticks","bricks"),
                   wolf = c("blow", "blow", "fail"))

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  print(colnames(df)[i])
  print(df[i])
}

[1] "pigs"
    pigs
1  straw
2 sticks
3 bricks
[1] "wolf"
  wolf
1 blow
2 blow
3 fail
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. So I'm actually getting colnames of the entire dataframe, but then just selecting the ```i```th value from that colnames vector?

Comment: yes - that's right.